# The problem is that the texts are overlapping in the Text View in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

**I created a text view using Storyboard and customized it with the following code. When I write a long text in the TextView and leave two lines of space, the texts overlap. How can I fix this? When I scroll, the texts become aligned.**

[image: textView]

```
private func setupTextView() {
        descriptionTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 24)
        descriptionTextView.text = AddAnnouncementConstants.descriptionPlaceholder
        descriptionTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
        descriptionTextView.delegate = self
    }

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = AddAnnouncementConstants.descriptionPlaceholder
            textView.textColor = .darkGray
            textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
        } else {
            textView.textColor = .dark1
        }
        updateButtonEnability()
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if let oldString = textView.text, oldString == AddAnnouncementConstants.descriptionPlaceholder && !text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = ""
        }
        updateButtonEnability()
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text == AddAnnouncementConstants.descriptionPlaceholder {
            textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
        }
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.vBorderColor = .dark1
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = AddAnnouncementConstants.descriptionPlaceholder
        }
        textView.vBorderColor = .lightGray
    }
```

Comment: Try making your insets negative.  IIRC a positive inset shrinks the frame and so will cause overlap.  Check out the documentation.